# How to use 'function(x)' in R?

Tags: r, syntax, quantile

I'm trying to define a simple function (x) in r that returns the minimum, medium and maximum of another dataframe (rate) as its own dataframe (my_quantile). I keep getting the 'unexpected symbol' error... can anyone please spot what is wrong with my syntax?

```
my_quantile <- function(x){r <- quantile(x, c(0,0.5,1))data.frame(minimum=r[1],median=r[2],maximum=r[3])} murders %>% filter(region == "West") %>% summarize(my_quantile(rate))
```

Just to confuse things, it seems that writing the code across multiple lines (like this):

```
> my_quantile <- function(x){
+     r <-  quantile(x, c(0, 0.5, 1))
+     data.frame(minimum = r[1], median = r[2], maximum = r[3]) 
+ }
> murders %>% 
+     filter(region == "West") %>%
+     summarize(my_quantile(rate))
```

... works and gives me

```
minimum   median  maximum
1 0.514592 1.292453 3.629527
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: If you want to put multiple R statements on one line, you need to separate them with `;`

Comment: Good habit when you build a function is to have dummy values for each of your argument so you can launch it once and see if there is any error. Here, `r` won't understand the fact that every row is stacked without `;` : e.g. `c(0,0.5,1))data.frame`

Comment: Please provide sample input to debug the code.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the `murders` data you have here, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg